# Singular bivariate distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, singular-integrals, singular-measures

It is known that singular copulas with prescribed support do not have a density, i.e. $\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf { C } \left( u _ { 1 } , u _ { 2 } \right)}{\partial u_1 \partial u_2} = 0$. For example, the upper Fréchet–Hoeffding bound is a singular copula, and is defined as:
$$\mathbf { C }\left( u _ { 1 } , \ldots , u _ { d } \right) = \min \left\{ u _ { 1 } , \ldots , u _ { d } \right\}$$

[Scatterplots of Comonotonicity Copula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSgyQ.png)

which concentrates the probability mass uniformly on $\left\{ (u_1,  u_2) \in [0,1]^2 : u _ { 1 } = u _ { 2 } \right\}$

**My question is:** How the copula distribution $\mathbf { C } \left( u _ { 1 } , u _ { 2 } \right)$ is then obtained, if we cannot integrate over the singular support.
[3d graph of Comonotonicity Copula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLi4H.png)

Comment: The copula $C(x,y)=\min\{x,y\}$ corresponds to the distribution of $(X,X)$ where the random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. This measure $\mu$ is concentrated on the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ and such that, for every 2-dim Borel set $B$, $\mu(B)=\mathrm{Leb}(\Delta_B)$, where $\Delta_B:=\{x\in(0,1)\in\mathbb R\mid(x,x)\in B\}$.

Comment: Many thanks @Did, I have limited knowledge of measure theory; can the above be explained in words. I have read somewhere that this set has Lebesgue measure of zero, would not $\mu ( B ) = \operatorname { Leb } \left( \Delta _ { B } \right)=0$?

Comment: No, because $\Delta_B\subset\mathbb R$ hence $\mathrm{Leb}$ in the formula is the 1-dim Lebesgue measure. Please reread more carefully my comment.

Comment: Thanks @Did, can you recommend any textbook/material that will be helpful to understand this particular problem?

Comment: Any probability theory (in the measure theoretical sense) textbook.

Comment: Thanks for the patience @Did, my last question is: what does it mean "uniformly distributed on (0,1)", and why the measure of 2-dim Borel set , is equal to the 1-dim Lebesgue measure? i.e. $\mu ( B ) = \operatorname { Leb } \left( \Delta _ { B } \right)$

Comment: Sorry but you are in copulas and you cannot fathom the meaning of the phrase "uniformly distributed on (0,1)"? Then something is very wrong here...

Comment: Thanks @Did for this :) I got it, it is just the phrase "concentrates the probability mass uniformly on $(0,1)$" did not seem to me the same as "uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$"! The second part of the question is still unclear to me: "why the measure of 2-dim Borel set , is equal to the 1-dim Lebesgue measure? i.e. ()=Leb(Δ)".

Comment: And if this is not clear from my first comment, we might have a noticeable problem with some lacking prerequisites...

Comment: Apologies @Did, that's correct, I do not have knowledge of measure theory (I have stats background only), and hence I decided to seek help here. I have tried to read up a little bit, which is fine at the beginning, but then it gets complicated very rapidly. Moreover, the stuff I read does not seem to be directly relevant to this situation; and maybe it will take some time before I find my answer. This maybe trivial to people of knowledge but to me its _terra incognita_. I thought this could be explained in layman's terms, but it seems to be not that easy to explain.

Comment: But your answers did, to some extent, dissipate a cloud of confusion. For which I'm very grateful! Thanks a lot!